# Invalid data shown in Redis Search filter

Tags: .net, filter, redis, redis-search, redis-om

I'm currently using RedisOM framework to communicate with redis db to filter some data. I'm trying to filter with Country, Status and System, my expectation in my filter will be an empty or no result, but it always retrieve some data.

Here's my query.

> var data = _games.Where(s =>
> s.Country == "Japan" && s.Releases.Any(s => s.Status == "Released" && s.System == "Mobile")).ToList();

Redis Data

> {
> "Id": 0,
> "GameName": "Pacman",
> "Country": "Japan",
> "Releases": [
> {
> "Status": "Released",
> "System": "PC"
> },
> {
> "Status": "Released",
> "System": "Console"
> },
> {
> "Status": "Pending",
> "System": "Mobile"
> }
> ]
> }

Generated script from Redis.

> "FT.SEARCH" "game-idx" "((@Country:{Japan}) ((@Releases_Status:{Released}) (@Releases_System:{Mobile})))" "LIMIT" "0" "100"

Indexes.
[my redis indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKqQe.png)

I've tried to query from the redis db but still showing a result.